# A word similar to 'inspire' which modifies the subject

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to construct a sentence saying that a pointed chin is a symbol of authority. My current sentence is "The general's [noun] inspires authority". I know that a more correct use of *inspire* here would be "inspires obedience", but I am looking for a correct way to keep this same sentence structure and use the word *authority*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bolster**

> to add to, support, or uphold

(Dictionary.com)

*His swagger bolsters his authority.*

Answer (score 0):

[Evoke](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/evoke)

> Bring or recall to the conscious mind
>   Ex: The sight of American asters evokes pleasant memories of childhood
>
> Elicit (a response)
>   Ex: The awkward kid who evoked giggles from his sisters